# CasperJS upload file without Form

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have this input :

```
 <input id="expertises" name="expertises" type="file" data-role="upload" multiple="multiple" autocomplete="off">
```

I need too upload file in, i don't have a form (it's a drag&drop). I try that :

```
casper.wait(1000).thenOpen(url+'/Affaidde/1267421/qsd', function() {
        this.page.uploadFile('input[id=expertises]', 'path');
    this.wait(5000, function() {
        this.echo("I've waited for a second.");
    });
});
```

But nothing happened (no error).
What is the problem ?

Thank's